# How to find the title of edx android app downloaded course video.?

Tags: android, sqlite, edx

I downloaded course videos using edx.org mobile app. Videos are saved in `/Android/data/org.edx.mobile/videos/some_random_alpha_numeric_string` directory. Subtitles are saved in `/Android/data/org.edx.mobile/videos/some_random_alpha_numeric_string/subtitles`. In both directories, files have random file names. I want to write a script to convert all those random names to actual video titles.

findings: I was browsing and found this document saying that there is a field called video_id retrieved from the server stored locally in SQLite database.